# HOC for Transition component

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I tried to write HOC for my Transitions in TransitionGroup.
Without HOC it looks like this:

```
...
<TransitionGroup>
          {this.state.show &&
            [1, 2, 3].map(item => (
              <Transition
                key={item}
                timeout={1000}
                addEndListener={this.endHandler(item)}
              >
                <Div />
              </Transition>
            ))}
        </TransitionGroup>  
...
```

You can see whole code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/yk612wro5v)

And I tried to separate animation to AnimationContainer Component:

AnimationContainer.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Transition } from "react-transition-group";

...

class AnimationContainer extends React.Component {
  endHandler = item => (n, done) => {
    // some animation functions here
  };

  render() {
    const { item, children } = this.props;
    return (
      <Transition timeout={1000} addEndListener={this.endHandler(item)}>
        {children}
      </Transition>
    );
  }
}

export default AnimationContainer;
```

But when I try to replace Transition with AnimationContainer it does not work. What is wrong with it?